# Authorized API returns HTML when the controller is hit and not the content

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have a very basic web API controller within an identity server project:

```
namespace Project.IDP.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

If I call this controller via Postman I receive an OK response 200 and the content 'Test', great.

However, if I add the Authorize attribute I receive HTML! The HTML is the login page of Identity Server. However, I have authorized and I'm passing the access token within the request (all via postman)

```
namespace Project.IDP.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

My client is setup like this:

new Client
{
ClientId= "m2m",
ClientName = "Machine 2 Machine Client",
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
ClientSecrets =
{
new Secret("secret".Sha256())
},
AllowedScopes = {
IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName,
"myapi.mi_test"
}
},

the API is like this:

```
    new ApiResource[]
    {
        new ApiResource(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName),
        new ApiResource("myapi", "My API" )
        {
            Scopes = new List<Scope>
            {
                new Scope("myapi.mi_test", "MI Access")
            }
        }
    };
```

In my startup class have tried:

```
    services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
```

and

```
    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:31101";
                options.ApiName = "myapi";
            });
```

But I can't get it to work, what am I missing?

Comment: I am afraid you will have to show your startup file of the webapi site if you want some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup, the only difference is that you need to specify the specific auth policy in your Authorize attribute.  In your "MyController" change your Authorize attribute to:

```
[Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)]
```

This requirement is shown in the IdenityServer docs at:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Lewis. This works but I do have a however...

I what to take this a step further and have a custom policy and then use the Authorize Attribute with that policy. As soon as I do that I have the same problem, html is just returned.

I'll post another question if you fancy helping again...

Comment: @Sun, looks like someone already answered that question for us.  ;)   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394565/identityserver4-localapi-with-custom-policy-net-core-3-1

Comment: Ah, let me give it a try.